# QT return value from a signal?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm running all my SQLite database operations in a separate thread to ensure that the GUI wont freeze up.

I'm doing this by connecting up signals and slots for the methods.

However now I need to find a way for the SQLite thread to return selected values to my main thread.

My header file:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

// ....
// ....

signals:
    QString getUserNickS(QString channel);  
}  

class dbThread : public QObject
{
     Q_OBJECT

public:
     dbThread();

public slots:
     bool openDB(QString agentID);
     QString getUserNick(QString channel);

private:
     QSqlDatabase db;
};
```

I then open the DB connection inside `MainWindow` in a separate thread like this:

```
// Start database thread
QThread * thread = new QThread();
dbtrad = new dbThread();
dbtrad - > moveToThread(thread);

//dbtrad->openDB(agentID);
connect(this, SIGNAL(requestOpenDB(QString)), dbtrad, SLOT(openDB(QString)));
connect(this, SIGNAL(getUserNickS(QString)), dbtrad, SLOT(getUserNick(QString)));

thread - > start();

emit requestOpenDB(userID);
```

And finally at one point in my application I want to query the SQLite db for some info and receive a return value: (still inside `MainWindow`)

```
QString retVal = getUserNickS(channelId);
qDebug() << "RET VALUE -----> " + retVal;
```

The `getUserNick` method looks like this:

```
// Returns visitor nickname for a channelId
QString dbThread::getUserNick(QString channel) {
    bool ret = false;

    if (db.isOpen()) {
        QSqlQuery query(db);

        ret = query.exec(QString("select * from visitorInfo WHERE channelID = '%1' order by date(time) ASC LIMIT 1;").arg(channel));

        if (ret) {
            bool gotResults = false;
            while (query.next()) {
              gotResults = true;
              qDebug() << query.value(14).toString();
              return query.value(14).toString();
            }
            if (!gotResults) {
                qDebug() << "Name " + channel.replace("V", "");
                return "Name " + channel.replace("V", "");
            }

        } else {
            qDebug() << "Name " + channel.replace("V", "");
            return "Name " + channel.replace("V", "");
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas how I can get the returned value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a connection of type Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection when the emitter and receiver are in different threads.

So it should be like:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(getUserNickS(QString)), dbtrad, SLOT(getUserNick(QString)),Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection);
```

When you emit your signal, it causes the current thread to block until the slot is returned.

Comment: You could also [invoke the method directly](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod) in that case.

Comment: @Alosyius, if an answer to your question is correct, please mark it as such by selecting the tick mark next to the up/down vote icons for that answer. Not only does it give credit to the person who took time to help you out, but it also saves time from people who read your question only to find out at the end that it has already been answered correctly.

Comment: @Merlin069: I think they have 15 minutes limit for that, but I agree.

Comment: @Merlin069 Sorry was waiting on the timer limit for that :)

Comment: This essentially defeats the purpose of having a second thread if the implementation of `getUserNick` accesses the database. The canonical way to address such problems is to have two connections between pairs of signal/slots: one for the request, another one for the response.

Comment: @Alosyius, sorry I had forgotten about the time limit ;O)